# Electronic Design Software for Large Electronics

Tags: schematics

I have this gigantic box of electronics and was looking for something like Eagle (in the schematic sense) for large electronic constructs (something with components the size of an industrial power supply such as [TIS 500-124-230](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/319833.pdf)). Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The PSU you're referring to doesn't look extraordinarily large to me. Eagle should be able to handle this kind of dimensions.

Comment: Does the physical size of a power supply have any effect on its schematic representation?

Comment: I was more looking for something that may already have the components and be more suited for this kind of design (perhaps allow you to give wires colors, though I suppose with the Eagle labels we can type it out). Also @stevenvh thank you for the edit. It isnt a size thing, it's more that there are certain ways to draw these units, and the best way may be available in these programs. For example an outlet with a swtich that is present in the Schaffaur FN284 [link](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/FN284-10-06/817-1107-ND/1928687)

Comment: No schematic/layout package will have every component footprint you'll ever need waiting for you. Part of doing electronics work is building up (or buying, or subscribing to) a footprint library consisting of all the parts you usually run across. Eagle has a lot of footprints, and there are plenty more freely available on their site, but it's not complete by any means. I usually end up adding a dozen or so parts to my library each year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As AngryEE mentioned, you want to draw wiring diagrams rather than schematics.  These are designed to be constructed by hand, rather than by a PCB design shop, and they have very different regulations than PCBs.

One thing that you'll quickly discover is that you *must* label all your wires.  According to [NFPA 79, the Electrical Standard for Industrial Machinery](http://www.nfpa.org/catalog/product.asp?pid=7912&cookie_test=1), you must use the following voltage-based scheme for your electrical wiring:

> - Black: AC hot
> - Red: Switched AC hot
> - Yellow: AC hot from a another source
> - White: Neutral
> - Red with White tracer: switched neutral
> - Green or Green with tracer:  ground/earth ground
> - Blue: DC voltage like the output of your power supply
> - White w/Blue tracer: DC common

The result is that I'm likely to have hundreds of blue wires snaking their way through Panduit to various terminal blocks, IO controllers, and other peripherals on DIN rails in even a small 20" panel.  This means that you *must* have an intelligent way to name, label, and locate wires when you do updates or rework.

The usual method is to use a ladder diagram or ladder schematic (note that these are distinct from the 'ladder logic' used for programming PLCs, which often occur in the same areas...).  I've got a modicum of experience with this (as an intern at a company with probably 600 electrical panels on our production floor).  People wiser than I have decided that we'll use [AutoCAD Electrical](http://usa.autodesk.com/autocad-electrical/); (note that this is not an endorsement, I find the program to be a royal pain to use) but there are probably other programs for the purpose.  It comes with symbols for devices from many of the most popular manufacturers, though I don't know that the above supply will be in it.  Here's my addition of a Phoenix supply to a circuit I'm working on:

[image]

with some distribution and fusing here:

[image]

Those images (along with another couple hundred rungs) form the wiring diagram.  This all goes into the panel diagram, which is the wiring equivalent of a PCB layout:

[image]

Each of these terminals is listed on the wiring diagram, so wiring the panel is simply a matter of laying out the components as shown in the panel diagram, then opening the wiring diagram and working down the rungs of the ladder, printing labels and connecting wires to the indicated terminal.

This is the best way to deal with large boxes of electronics.  It may be unfamiliar to you, but it's a different task than designing a PCB.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something to draw wiring diagrams instead of schematics.  Wiring diagrams are distinct from schematics in that they show the connections between connectors and components rather than describe the interconnections of a circuit (like you might find on a PCB).  For this purpose I would recommend Visio or its open source clone Dia.  They're pretty well suited for that sort of work - you can add your power supply components as rectangles and define connection points on them for each wire to connect to.  The wires can be lines between rectangles that can have labels and different colors and possibly different thicknesses if you want to show wire gauge that way.  You also get a lot of annotation options like text boxes and such to make the diagram prettier and easier to read.

Comment: Visio and Dia will work, but they're not designed for the purpose.  Everything will be manual; there's no library management, wire drawing, or the like.  They'll work for one-offs or presentations in a pinch, but I wouldn't want to do more than a few simple panels with them.